Dynamically add IPv4 address or ranges to an Azure APIM Api Policy
I am trying to automate the building of my apim with TerraForm... it was going quite well until i have hit a wall :D
one of the policies needs to be restricted to a couple of ip addresses + 1 range, but the dev and prod adressess are different in different environments
eg
<ip-filter action="allow">
    <address>10.0.0.100</address>
    <address>10.0.0.101</address>
    <address-range from="10.0.0.200" to="10.0.0.209" />
    <address-range from="10.0.0.230" to="10.0.0.239" />
</ip-filter>

So i thought if i create a couple of NamedValue variables in the APIM using TF eg:
AllowedIPAddresses="10.0.0.100,10.0.0.101"
AllowedIPRanges="10.0.0.200-10.0.0.209,10.0.0.230-10.0.0.239"

These can easily be created and managed in different environments by TF and as long as i could split the comma separated address/ranges somehow in the policy eg
    <set-variable name="allowed-ips" value={{AllowedIPAddresses}}" />
    

Problem
I cannot seem to split the values up in the policy! when i create the api in TF, i am importing the policy xml from a file against the api's operation, so the policy needs to be as generic as possible and dependant on variables.
I did try a couple of the friendly neighbourhood helpers and they gave encouraging signs that it was possible using the .Split  and for each statements but i could not seem to get to a place were the syntax was accepted on saving the policy, eg the following the portal says there is an error (marked >>>) : An error occurred while parsing EntityName.
<inbound>
    <base />
    <!-- read the NamedValue variable into a local variable
    <set-variable name="ipList" value="{{AllowedIPAddresses}}" />

    <!-- Split the list into an array
    <set-variable name="ipArray" value="@((string)context.Variables["ipList"]).Split(',')" />

    <set-variable name="allowedIps" value="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("ipList").Split(','))" />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string[]>("allowedIps").Length > 0)">
            <ip-filter action="allow">
                @foreach (var ip in context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string[]>("allowedIps"))
                {
>>>               <address>@(ip)</address>
                }
            </ip-filter>
        </when>
    </choose>
    ...
    ...
</inbound>

any advice or maybe other approaches would be appreciated

Can you share the complete code here.

main description updated @Jahnavi

Are you still looking for an approach. @manneym
